# SCSS - Hover effect extends to other elements

Tags: html, css

Why is the hover effect of the minus button triggered even when I hover the input field or plus button?

```css
.changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv {
  --input-height: 22px;
  --label-height: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 120px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv .changeHoursSpendContentDiv {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 38px;
  bottom: 38px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

.changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv .changeHoursSpendContentDiv .changeHoursSpendLabelDiv {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: var(--label-height);
  line-height: var(--label-height);
}

.changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv .changeHoursSpendContentDiv .changeHoursSpendDiv {
  position: absolute;
  left: 120px;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  height: var(--input-height);
}

.changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv .changeHoursSpendContentDiv .changeHoursSpendButton {
  height: calc(var(--input-height) + 2px);
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv .changeHoursSpendContentDiv .changeHoursSpendButton:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv .changeHoursSpendContentDiv .changeHoursSpendButton:active {
  top: -1px;
}

.changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv .changeHoursSpendContentDiv .changeHoursSpendButton:disabled {
  background-color: grey;
}

.changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv .changeHoursSpendContentDiv .changeHoursSpendMinus {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
}

.changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv .changeHoursSpendContentDiv .changeHoursSpend {
  position: absolute;
  height: var(--input-height);
  text-align: right;
  left: 22px;
  width: 58px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid grey
}

.changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv .changeHoursSpendContentDiv .changeHoursSpendPlus {
  position: absolute;
  left: 84px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv">
  <div class="changeHoursSpendContentDiv">
    <div class="changeHoursSpendLabelDiv">
      Time spend
    </div>
    <div class="changeHoursSpendDiv">
      <label>
        <input type= "button" class = "changeHoursSpendButton changeHoursSpendMinus" value = "-">
        <input type= "text" class = "changeHoursSpend editInput" readonly>
        <input type= "button" class = "changeHoursSpendButton changeHoursSpendPlus" value = "+">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because labels also trigger the input element. You can also click a checkbox label, and then the checkbox will get checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you nested the inputs in a label. If you avoid the nesting it works:

```css
.changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv {
  --input-height: 22px;
  --label-height: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 120px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv .changeHoursSpendContentDiv {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 38px;
  bottom: 38px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

.changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv .changeHoursSpendContentDiv .changeHoursSpendLabelDiv {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: var(--label-height);
  line-height: var(--label-height);
}

.changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv .changeHoursSpendContentDiv .changeHoursSpendDiv {
  position: absolute;
  left: 120px;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  height: var(--input-height);
}

.changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv .changeHoursSpendContentDiv .changeHoursSpendButton {
  height: calc(var(--input-height) + 2px);
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv .changeHoursSpendContentDiv .changeHoursSpendButton:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv .changeHoursSpendContentDiv .changeHoursSpendButton:active {
  top: -1px;
}

.changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv .changeHoursSpendContentDiv .changeHoursSpendButton:disabled {
  background-color: grey;
}

.changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv .changeHoursSpendContentDiv .changeHoursSpendMinus {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
}

.changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv .changeHoursSpendContentDiv .changeHoursSpend {
  position: absolute;
  height: var(--input-height);
  text-align: right;
  left: 22px;
  width: 58px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid grey
}

.changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv .changeHoursSpendContentDiv .changeHoursSpendPlus {
  position: absolute;
  left: 84px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="changeHoursSpendTemplateDiv">
  <div class="changeHoursSpendContentDiv">
    <div class="changeHoursSpendLabelDiv">
      Time spend
    </div>
    <div class="changeHoursSpendDiv">
      <label></label>
      <input type="button" class="changeHoursSpendButton changeHoursSpendMinus" value="-">
      <input type="text" class="changeHoursSpend editInput" readonly>
      <input type="button" class="changeHoursSpendButton changeHoursSpendPlus" value="+">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The label should already only be around the input field. Doesn't know what came over me to wrap it around the buttons.